# RUN yarn doesn't create node_modules inside docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile that should build an image of a node. In the build phase, it builds right, however, in the production phase, the node_modules folder does not appear inside the image.

I'm not mapping any volumes, just trying to build the image. Could anyone help me with this? I don't understand why this is happening.

```
FROM node:16.14-alpine3.15 as builder

ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json .
COPY tsconfig.json .
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

FROM node:16.14-alpine3.15 as production

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
VOLUME /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir logs

COPY package*.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install --production

RUN ls -la
RUN ls -la node_modules

COPY --from=builder /home/node/app/dist /usr/src/app/dist

EXPOSE 3333
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

[image]

Comment: Do all dependencies on package.json lie under “devDependencies”?

Comment: No. There are dependencies in dependencies and devDependencies.

Comment: I found that it has something to do with having declared in the Dockerfile that the Workdir is a volume. But I don't understand why all the contents are there with the exception of node_modules.

Comment: maybe you have node_modules inside .dockerignore file and that affects the volume

Comment: Yes, the `VOLUME` line is unnecessary and can cause strange problems like this, and you can just delete it.  If that's not enough, can you [edit] the question to include the actual error message, and not an image attachment?

Comment: I removed the line from the Dockerfile and it worked. But it's strange behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I'm working with yarn 4.0.2.

As new yarn versions supports three ways to install your project's dependencies, `node_modules` is not the first option on an empty project (usual behavior when define steps follow in Dockerfile)

```yaml
#.yarnrc.yml 
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

copy .yarnrc.yml file:

```
COPY  .yarnrc.yml ./
```

copy .yarn folder:

```
COPY .yarn ./.yarn
```

and copy `yarnrc.yml` with [nodeLinker: node-modules](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#nodeLinker) option

Here is my Dockerfile for Nextjs, node 20 and Yarn 4.0.2
https://gist.github.com/molavec/89a184c8f257e2a025ebb1d63691c288